# Mint unable to boot: no inputs registered

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, boot

Last month I set up a Linux Mint install all my computer for development. The install was on its own partition on a HDD separate from my usual Windows boot.

Today I was working away for a couple hours when I started being unable to save any of my files due to a "Read only file system error" that looks exactly [how this user describes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659182/linux-mint-read-only-file-system-error).

My first instinct is of course to reboot. After selecting my Linux install from the boot menu I'm greeted with this message:

```
hid-generic 0003:1532:024E.0007: No inputs registered, leaving
```

[image]

That's as far as I get. I don't know how to figure out *what* is not being registered, but judging from the preceding issue it's probably the hard drive or something, which otherwise works fine from my Windows boot.

Comment: Yes, it's likely a fatal drive failure. The read-only state prior to the incident was the warning.

Comment: The drive is a year old, and appears to read and write perfectly fine on windows.

Comment: Are Windows and Mint in the same drive?

Comment: The `hid-generic` error message refers to Human Interface Devices, not storage devices. The numbers suggest it might be about a [Razer BlackWidow V3](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/1532/024e) gaming keyboard. Can you type in commands at that point? Try `lsblk` or `cat /proc/partitions` to find out which drives have been successfully detected.

Comment: @telcoM
`cat /proc/partitions` worked, but the results didn't really mean anything to me. I assumed it correctly listed all my partitions. I've resolved my issue and updated my question with what I did. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim I typed `exit` into the console on this boot screen. When I did that I got a message about my OS being corrupt and it recommended a command to run (I think it was `fsck` but I can't remember for sure).

I ran the command on the partition Linux is installed on, and it went through and repaired a bunch of blocks and inodes that were corrupt or missing and afterwards I was able to boot with no data lost.